# HTML script to split browser into three different webpages

Tags: browser, split

I had a friend create an html file for me once that split my browser into three different panes dependent on the website I defined. I used this for work till my laptop died and it worked in IE, FF, and Chrome flawlessly.

I lost the html file though so I don't know exactly how he did it. I did know how to edit the website that pulled up within each pane that was defined by " " and came here for assistance. I know there are some addons for this but it worked with all three browsers and was interchangeable so it was extremely helpful to have. Any assistance would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

He probably used 3 iframes:

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" style="width:32%; height:100%; display:inline;"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" style="width:32%; height:100%; display:inline;"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" style="width:32%; height:100%; display:inline;"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: He did use something extremely similar to this, all though I was able to adjust the pane up and down. Also instead of having these two pages side to side, is it possible to have them on top of each other, webpage 1 on top, then webpage 2 on bottom with this script?

Comment: after some research I believed he did this with borders, but I was able to adjust the src code with whatever domain I chose. Any idea?